# Can I define a common interface for two classes with same property name?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have following class hierarchy:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
```

And I have two container classes:

```
class BContainer { public B[] value { get; set; } }
class CContainer { public C[] value { get; set; } }
```

I need to define a method that can accept either of the two class instances and can access the `value` property without resorting to reflection. Is there a way I can define an interface (say `IContainer`) that both of the classes can implement? If so, what would be the type of the `value` property in the interface?

Example usage:

```
void ProcessValue(IEnumerable<A> as) { ... }

void ExtractValue(IContainer container)
{
    ProcessValue(container.value);
}
```

Comment: Cant you make the Value property of type A[]

Comment: No, the container type is actually used for deserialization in my project. E.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BContainer>(serializedString).value);`

Comment: You can only create an interface that is a subset of the base class A.  You can then make an interface A and cast is to either B or C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a good case for generics:

```
class Container<T> where T : A
{ 
    public T[] value { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I chose this as solution as this allowed me to remove definitions of classes `BContainer` and `CContainer`. In case the container classes had other members unique to them, then the solution proposed by @Dmitry was the way to go. I will definitely go through all other answers. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You could define the interface as:

```
interface IContainer<T>
    where T : A
{
    T[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you classes would be:

```
class BContainer : IContainer<B> { public B[] Value { get; set; } }
class CContainer : IContainer<C> { public C[] Value { get; set; } }
```

And then the processing method should be generic too:

```
void ExtractValue<T>(IContainer<T> container)
    where T : A
{
    ProcessValue(container.Value);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the user is looking for an API that takes a non-generic `IContainer`, as in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the type of the property differs in the two classes the type should be a common type for the two properties. In this case `IEnumerable<A>` should do fine. The problem is that the two properties you define cannot be the implementation for this interface, you could use explicit interface implementation do define a separate property with the same name that servers as the implementation for the interface property.

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
interface IContainer
{
    IEnumerable<A> value { get; }
}
class BContainer : IContainer
{
    public B[] value { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<A> IContainer.value => this.value;
}
class CContainer : IContainer
{
    public C[] value { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<A> IContainer.value => this.value;
}
```

This property used for explicit implementation will be hidden from the outside and from inside the class. If you access `this.value` you are accessing the class version of value, unless the reference is cast explicitly to `IContainer` (ex `((IContainer)this).value` this will access the interface version of the property)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
public class C : A { }

public interface IContainer
{
    A[] value { get; }
}

class BContainer : IContainer { public B[] value { get; set; } A[] IContainer.value { get { return this.value; } } }
class CContainer : IContainer { public C[] value { get; set; } A[] IContainer.value { get { return this.value; } } }

void ProcessValue(IEnumerable<A> arg) { }

void ExtractValue(IContainer container)
{
    ProcessValue(container.value);
}
```

This compiles at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single non-generic `IContainer` that you can treat both collections as *identically*, then there's not really a very clean option, because the *type* is different. Variance hates type difference. You could use *generics*, sure, but that would help you because you'd need to check each closed generic type separately, just like you'd currently need to check for `B` and `C` separately.

The closest you could get *easily* on a non-generic API would be returning `Array` or `IList` (non-generic) in `IContainer`, which is horrible and doesn't move you forward much.

Alternatively, if you only need to *enumerate* the items, you can use the variance features of generics to get the items as the base type:

```
class BContainer : IContainer
{
    public B[] value { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<A> IContainer.Value => value;
}
class CContainer : IContainer
{
    public C[] value { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<A> IContainer.Value => value;
}

interface IContainer
{
    IEnumerable<A> Value { get; }
}
```

Both `BContainer` and `CContainer` can be treated as an `IContainer`, and given an `IContainer` you can iterate the items *as `A`s*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure these generic answers would work for your serialization requirements.

What about some overloads?

```
void ExtractValue(BContainer container)
{
    ProcessValue(container.Value);
}

void ExtractValue(CContainer container)
{
    ProcessValue(container.Value);
}
```

Comment: Json.NET deserializer works well for generic types: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<B>>(serializedString).‌​value)`.

Comment: That's true, I was thinking more that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(serializedString‌​).‌​value)` wouldn't work and overloads might resolve that.